# Advanced styling of input number spinners in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've successfully styled the `::-webkit-inner-spin-button` and `::-webkit-outer-spin-button` of a `input[type=number]` tag with an image.

However I have two issues.

1. The "inner" and "outer" buttons do not correspond to the increment and decrement halves of the single image. And so you cannot distinguish between `:active` on the top or bottom and apply a new style to one or the other to indicate activation.
2. This should be simpler, but I can't figure out how to also set a new style when the input comes into focus. I've tried the following two permutations of selectors.

   ```
   input.welcome-input[type=number]:focus input.welcome-input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
   input.welcome-input[type=number]:focus input.welcome-input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
   ```

   and

   ```
   input.welcome-input[type=number]:focus ::-webkit-inner-spin-button, ::-webkit-outer-spin-button
   ```

Anyone know of a way to get around these?

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/WwfW9/)

Comment: You should give us a working fiddle, it will help your question out a lot

Comment: Thanks, I added one.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution for that, we will soon see though.